# Error using xlswrite (line 219) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, xls

while I run the following code, an example in matlab:

```
filename = 'testdata.xlsx';
A = [12.7 5.02 -98 63.9 0 -.2 56];
xlswrite(filename,A)
```

I get the error

```
Error using xlswrite (line 219)
```

I have already tried to slove this problem. I reinstall office, and reinstall matlab, but i doesn't work. However, the above code is valid in other PC.

Comment: Is this the full error log? We cannot recreate this at our end, so it is essential that we have everything. Also, can you try writing it as a txt file and see if it works? Also check your OS, if windows, try to run matlab in Admin mode as it sometimes chokes on file creation into protected drive path.

Comment: An error in line 219 means that Microsoft Excel cannot access the provided file. Maybe the file already exist and is locked (eg: if you have it open with Excel).

Answer (score 0):

Try using csvwrite instead of xlswrite. Both can be read by excel, but csvwrite will be less buggy to office installations. If csvwrite works, then you can look further into office compatability issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the Windows Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc), then click on "More details", in "Processes" find and close all excel processes and then run your code.