# xlsread、xlswrite not work in matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

matlab (2015b) in my new notebook ThinkPad function xlsread/ xlswrite not work

for every exist excel file， xlsread not load the data
xlswrite also not work in every path
error use xlsread (line251)

```
 catch exception
        if isempty(exception.identifier)
            exception = MException('MATLAB:xlsreadold:FormatError','%s', exception.message);
        end
        throw(exception);
```

the method import data also not work for excel file。

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us some of your code (and test data will always be helpflul). Otherwise it will be hard to identify the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35699929/6064915.the similar question.values = {1, 2, 3 ; 4, 5, 'x' ; 7, 8, 9};
headers = {'First','Second','Third'};
xlswrite('myExample.xlsx',[headers; values]);

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer in 
https://cn.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/282688-why-my-excel-file-can-not-be-read-by-matlab hope it can help you:

Who has problem to read excel file, can follow this order.

1- open the excel> file, >option, >add in, manage then select COM ADD IN, and clear everything (unchecked). everything should be cleared (unchecked).

2- restart the PC, and open the matlab.

3- perform xlsread command.

NOTE: for those people who use foxit pdf reader, it is potential to face this problem, so follow mentioned order.

NOTE: sometimes by using the matlab, configuration of excel is changed in unknown way, therefore there is no way to open the usual excel file in windows by double click.

So, open excel from desktop icon, file> option,> advanced,> general and then make clear (unchecked) "the ignore applications that use dynamic data exchange (DDE)". (same information for NOTE 2: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3001579) these are some error for excel worker with matlab and related command.